# Unitary matrix and Standard Hermitian inner product basic question

Tags: linear-algebra

So this question is bothering me from a long time. I know all the major properties of unitary matrix but I am missing, how can I prove that $\langle Uv\mid Uw\rangle=\langle v \mid w\rangle$?
It seems to be quite easy for field to be $\mathbb R$, can I get some idea about how can I prove this for field to be $\mathbb C$? Where $U$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and $x,y$ are $n\times 1$ matrix in $\mathbb C$.

---

This is probably a basic question, but I am revisiting linear algebra after a long time. So, it seems to be weird.

Comment: Do you know that 
$$
\langle Av \mid Bw \rangle = \langle v \mid A^\dagger B w \rangle
$$
where $A^\dagger$ denotes the adjoint of $A$?

Comment: I know about the adjoint of A, but I don't have ant idea about that identity.

Comment: That's probably the key piece of information that you're missing

Comment: Yup, it is the identity then everything is sorted.
Thank you very much!